# python генератор уникальных слов

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.x, словари, генерация-случайных-данных

Запутался, помогите, подскажите

Задача кода написать 3 буквенное слово которое не будет повторятся в списке

```
import random

z = 0
def listSec(s):
    listSec = ''
    listSec = listSec + s + '\n'
    return listSec
listToPrint = ''

while z < 160:
    sec = ''.join(random.choice('abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz') for i in range(3))
    for i in range(len(listToPrint)):
        if sec != listToPrint[i]:
            print (z)
            listToPrint += listSec(sec)
            z += 1

def equal(s, listReit = '', a = 0):
    for i in range(len(s)):
        print (i)
        if s[i] == s[i + 1]:
            print(s[i])
            a = a + 1
            listReit = listReit + s[i]
            print ('reiterative: %s' % (s[i]))
            return a, listReit
    print ('Value reiterative: %s, \nlist: %s' % (a, listReit))

#equal(listToPrint)

print (listToPrint)
```

Сейчас консоль просто зависает без какого либо ответа

upd:

```
import random

z = 0
def listSec(s):
    listSec = ''
    listSec = listSec + s + '\n'
    return listSec
listToPrint = []

while z < 160:
    sec = ''.join(random.choice('abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz') for i in range(3))

    a = 0
    while a < 1:
        listToPrint += listSec(sec)
        a = a + 1

    for i in range(len(listToPrint)):
        k = i + 1
        if listSec[i] != listSec[k]:
            print (z)
            listToPrint += listSec(sec)
            z += 1

print (listToPrint)
input('press key for exit')
```

Comment: `len(listToPrint) = 0`, следовательно, вы не входите в цикл `for i in range(len(listToPrint))` и переменная `z` так и остается нулем.

Comment: Если нужно много слов сгенерировать и производительность имеет значение, то можно много случайных байт за раз генерировать и разбивать их на слова, добавляя в набор (set) и повторять процесс пока нужное число слов не сгенерируется, [пример кода, демонстрирующий несколько трюков по оптимизации](http://stackoverflow.com/a/16310739/4279)

Comment: Если вы эти строки в паролях или похожих вещах хотите использовать, то используйте `random.SystemRandom()` или `os.urandom()` напрямую вместо `random.Random()`, используемый по умолчанию. См., также [secrets модуль](https://docs.python.org/dev/library/secrets.html)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
import random, string

listToPrint = set()
while len(listToPrint) < 160:
    listToPrint.add(''.join(random.choice(string.ascii_lowercase) for i in range(3)))
print(listToPrint)
```

создать файл:

```
import os
path = 'logs'
for num, name in enumerate(os.listdir(path)):
    name_, _ext = os.path.splitext(name)
    print(num, name)
    n = [name_, num.__repr__(), _ext]
    print(n)
    newfile = os.path.join(path, ''.join(n))
    with open(newfile, 'w') as f:
        data = open(os.path.join(path, name))
        f.write(data.read())
```

out:

```
0 asd.log
['asd', '0', '.log']
1 qwe.log
['qwe', '1', '.log']
2 zxc.log
['zxc', '2', '.log']
```

Comment: Позанудствую: в оригинальном вопросе в генерируемых словах не используется буква `a` :)

Comment: нужно без повторов!
Обязательна проверка на повторы

Comment: @ALPHA повторов нету!, почитайте о типе данных set.

Comment: @vadimvaduxa, спасибо за инфу о set!

Comment: Может еще подскажите как лучше прочитать название файла в папке, к названию добавить + 1 (name -> name1) и создать файл?

Comment: @ALPHA добавил в ответ

Comment: @vadimvaduxa, спасибо, вот только я имел ввиду не (name1 - name11 - name111) а (name1 - name2 - name3)

Comment: воспользуйтесь enumerate: for num, name in enumerate(os.listdir(path)):

Comment: @vadimvaduxa, как я понял, он просто индексирует список (то же, что и просто обратится по индексу)
Ладно, что-то придумаю